# (C#) How to modify attribute's value in the existing XML file without loading or rewriting the whole file?

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xmlreader, xmlwriter

I'm making some huge XML files (several GB) with the help of XmlWriter and Linq2Xml.
This files are of type:

```
<Table recCount="" recLength="">
<Rec recId="1">..</Rec>
<Rec recId="2">..</Rec>
..
<Rec recId="n">..</Rec>
</Table>
```

I don't know values for *Table's* *recCount* and *recLength* attributes until I write all the inner *Rec* nodes, so I have to write values to these attributes at the very end.

Right now I'm writing all the inner *Rec* nodes to a temp file, calculate *Table*'s attributes' values and write everything the way I've shown above to a resulting file. (copying everything from the temp file with all the *Rec* nodes)

**I'm wondering if there is a way to modify these attributes' values without writing stuff to another file (like I do it right now) or loading the whole document into memory (which is obviously not possible due to size of these files)?**

Comment: Yes it is, but you'll have to reserve some spaces for those numbers (you can't "insert" bytes in a file, you can only overwrite them)

Comment: @xanatos hm, well, I guess it would work as well. How can I do it?

Comment: Can you change the xml format? Put `count` and `length` *elements* at the end.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov unfortunately, this format is provided by our customers and there's no way for me to change it (even though it **should be changed**)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heavily commented code. The basic idea is that in the first pass we write:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Table recCount="$1" recLength="$2">
<!--Reserved space:++++++++++++++++-->
<Rec...
```

Then we go back to the beginning of the file and we rewrite the first three lines:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Table recCount="1000" recLength="150">
<!--Reserved space:#############-->
```

The important "trick" here is that you can't "insert" into a file, you can only overwrite it. So we "reserve" some space for the digits (the `Reserved space:#############.` comment. There are many many ways we could have done it... For example, in the first pass we could have:

```
<Table recCount="              " recLength="          ">
```

and then (xml-legal but ugly):

```
<Table recCount="1000          " recLength="150       ">
```

Or we could have appended the space *after* the `>` of Table:

```
<Table recCount="" recLength="">
```

(there are 20 spaces *after* the `>`)

Then:

```
<Table recCount="1000" recLength="150">
```

(now there are are 13 spaces *after* the `>`)

Or we could have simply added the spaces without the `<!-- -->` on a new line...

The code:

```
int maxRecCountLength = 10; // int.MaxValue.ToString().Length
int maxRecLengthLength = 10; // int.MaxValue.ToString().Length
int tokenLength = 4; // 4 == $1 + $2, see below what $1 and $2 are
// Note that the reserved space will be in the form +++++++++++++++++++

string reservedSpace = new string('+', maxRecCountLength + maxRecLengthLength - tokenLength); 

// You have to manually open the FileStream
using (var fs = new FileStream("out.xml", FileMode.Create))

// and add a StreamWriter on top of it
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fs, Encoding.UTF8, 4096, true))
{
    // Here you write on your StreamWriter however you want.
    // Note that recCount and recLength have a placeholder $1 and $2.
    int recCount = 0;
    int maxRecLength = 0;

    using (var xw = XmlWriter.Create(sw))
    {
        xw.WriteWhitespace("\r\n");
        xw.WriteStartElement("Table");
        xw.WriteAttributeString("recCount", "$1");
        xw.WriteAttributeString("recLength", "$2");

        // You have to add some white space that will be 
        // partially replaced by the recCount and recLength value
        xw.WriteWhitespace("\r\n");
        xw.WriteComment("Reserved space:" + reservedSpace);

        // <--------- BEGIN YOUR CODE
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            xw.WriteWhitespace("\r\n");
            xw.WriteStartElement("Rec");

            string str = string.Format("Some number: {0}", i);
            if (str.Length > maxRecLength)
            {
                maxRecLength = str.Length;
            }
            xw.WriteValue(str);

            recCount++;

            xw.WriteEndElement();
        }
        // <--------- END YOUR CODE

        xw.WriteWhitespace("\r\n");
        xw.WriteEndElement();
    }

    sw.Flush();

    // Now we read the first lines to modify them (normally we will
    // read three lines, the xml header, the <Table element and the
    // <-- Reserved space:
    fs.Position = 0;

    var lines = new List<string>();

    using (var sr = new StreamReader(fs, sw.Encoding, false, 4096, true))
    {
        while (true)
        {
            string str = sr.ReadLine();
            lines.Add(str);

            if (str.StartsWith("<Table"))
            {
                // We read the next line, the comment line
                str = sr.ReadLine();
                lines.Add(str);
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    string strCount = XmlConvert.ToString(recCount);
    string strMaxRecLength = XmlConvert.ToString(maxRecLength);

    // We do some replaces for the tokens
    int oldLen = lines[lines.Count - 2].Length;
    lines[lines.Count - 2] = lines[lines.Count - 2].Replace("=\"$1\"", string.Format("=\"{0}\"", strCount));
    lines[lines.Count - 2] = lines[lines.Count - 2].Replace("=\"$2\"", string.Format("=\"{0}\"", strMaxRecLength));
    int newLen = lines[lines.Count - 2].Length;

    // Remove spaces from reserved whitespace
    lines[lines.Count - 1] = lines[lines.Count - 1].Replace(":" + reservedSpace, ":" + new string('#', reservedSpace.Length - newLen + oldLen));

    // We move back to just after the UTF8/UTF16 preamble
    fs.Position = sw.Encoding.GetPreamble().Length;

    // And we rewrite the lines
    foreach (string str in lines)
    {
        sw.Write(str);
        sw.Write("\r\n");
    }
}
```

**Slower .NET 3.5 way**

In .NET 3.5 the `StreamReader`/`StreamWriter` want to close the base `FileStream`, so I have to reopen various times the file. This is a little little slower.

```
int maxRecCountLength = 10; // int.MaxValue.ToString().Length
int maxRecLengthLength = 10; // int.MaxValue.ToString().Length
int tokenLength = 4; // 4 == $1 + $2, see below what $1 and $2 are
                        // Note that the reserved space will be in the form +++++++++++++++++++

string reservedSpace = new string('+', maxRecCountLength + maxRecLengthLength - tokenLength);
string fileName = "out.xml";

int recCount = 0;
int maxRecLength = 0;

using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fileName))
{
    // Here you write on your StreamWriter however you want.
    // Note that recCount and recLength have a placeholder $1 and $2.
    using (var xw = XmlWriter.Create(sw))
    {
        xw.WriteWhitespace("\r\n");
        xw.WriteStartElement("Table");
        xw.WriteAttributeString("recCount", "$1");
        xw.WriteAttributeString("recLength", "$2");

        // You have to add some white space that will be 
        // partially replaced by the recCount and recLength value
        xw.WriteWhitespace("\r\n");
        xw.WriteComment("Reserved space:" + reservedSpace);

        // <--------- BEGIN YOUR CODE
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
        {
            xw.WriteWhitespace("\r\n");
            xw.WriteStartElement("Rec");

            string str = string.Format("Some number: {0}", i);
            if (str.Length > maxRecLength)
            {
                maxRecLength = str.Length;
            }
            xw.WriteValue(str);

            recCount++;

            xw.WriteEndElement();
        }
        // <--------- END YOUR CODE

        xw.WriteWhitespace("\r\n");
        xw.WriteEndElement();
    }
}

var lines = new List<string>();

using (var sr = new StreamReader(fileName))
{
    // Now we read the first lines to modify them (normally we will
    // read three lines, the xml header, the <Table element and the
    // <-- Reserved space:

    while (true)
    {
        string str = sr.ReadLine();
        lines.Add(str);

        if (str.StartsWith("<Table"))
        {
            // We read the next line, the comment line
            str = sr.ReadLine();
            lines.Add(str);
            break;
        }
    }
}

// We have to use the Stream overload of StreamWriter because
// we want to modify the text!
using (var fs = File.OpenWrite(fileName))
using (var sw = new StreamWriter(fs))
{
    string strCount = XmlConvert.ToString(recCount);
    string strMaxRecLength = XmlConvert.ToString(maxRecLength);

    // We do some replaces for the tokens
    int oldLen = lines[lines.Count - 2].Length;
    lines[lines.Count - 2] = lines[lines.Count - 2].Replace("=\"$1\"", string.Format("=\"{0}\"", strCount));
    lines[lines.Count - 2] = lines[lines.Count - 2].Replace("=\"$2\"", string.Format("=\"{0}\"", strMaxRecLength));
    int newLen = lines[lines.Count - 2].Length;

    // Remove spaces from reserved whitespace
    lines[lines.Count - 1] = lines[lines.Count - 1].Replace(":" + reservedSpace, ":" + new string('#', reservedSpace.Length - newLen + oldLen));

    // We move back to just after the UTF8/UTF16 preamble
    sw.BaseStream.Position = sw.Encoding.GetPreamble().Length;

    // And we rewrite the lines
    foreach (string str in lines)
    {
        sw.Write(str);
        sw.Write("\r\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: Somehow I had problems starting after using StreamReader when I tried to set `fs.Position` gettiing an exception **cannot access closed file**. I tried to put an additional paramter into a FileStream ctor (something about  access rights for other streams to this file), but it didn't help. Also, there was a problem with FileStream, StreamWriter and StreamReader's ctors - there was something wrong with parameters. I guess that there might be some changes in this in future C# and .Net versions, (I have to use 3 and 3.5). But anyway, I like your aproach and it worked great. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @PayshaYugen Normally the `StreamReader` will auto-close its base stream when it is disposed. You must prevent it to do this. The parameters I used (the last `true` to be exact) are for this reason.

Comment: Thank you for this information! I'll check once again later, what was the problem with parameters in *Stream constructors. I got rid of `StreamReader` by creating the `lines` List at the very beginning and saved the required information into it while passing data into a file. So I didn't have to read it afterwards.

Comment: @PayshaYugen Sadly in .NET 3.5 the `keepAlive` parameter isn't present. Posted an alternative that closes and reopens the file.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use the following approach.

You can set the default value to the attributes in the external xml schema.

When creating an xml document, you do not create these attributes. Here it is:

```
int count = 5;
int length = 42;

var writerSettings = new XmlWriterSettings { Indent = true };
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create("data.xml", writerSettings))
{
    writer.WriteStartElement("Table");

    for (int i = 1; i <= count; i++)
    {
        writer.WriteStartElement("Rec");
        writer.WriteAttributeString("recId", i.ToString());
        writer.WriteString("..");
        writer.WriteEndElement();
    }
}
```

Thus, the xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Table>
  <Rec recId="1">..</Rec>
  <Rec recId="2">..</Rec>
  <Rec recId="3">..</Rec>
  <Rec recId="4">..</Rec>
  <Rec recId="5">..</Rec>
</Table>
```

Now create an xml schema for this document, which will specify the default values to the desired attributes.

```
string ns = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";
using (var writer = XmlWriter.Create("data.xsd", writerSettings))
{
    writer.WriteStartElement("xs", "schema", ns);

    writer.WriteStartElement("xs", "element", ns);
    writer.WriteAttributeString("name", "Table");

    writer.WriteStartElement("xs", "complexType", ns);
    writer.WriteStartElement("xs", "sequence", ns);

    writer.WriteStartElement("xs", "any", ns);
    writer.WriteAttributeString("processContents", "skip");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("maxOccurs", "unbounded");
    writer.WriteEndElement();

    writer.WriteEndElement();

    writer.WriteStartElement("xs", "attribute", ns);
    writer.WriteAttributeString("name", "recCount");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("default", count.ToString()); // <--
    writer.WriteEndElement();

    writer.WriteStartElement("xs", "attribute", ns);
    writer.WriteAttributeString("name", "recLength");
    writer.WriteAttributeString("default", length.ToString()); // <--
    writer.WriteEndElement();
}
```

Or much easier to create a schema as following:

```
XNamespace xs = "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema";

var schema = new XElement(xs + "schema",
    new XElement(xs + "element", new XAttribute("name", "Table"),
        new XElement(xs + "complexType",
            new XElement(xs + "sequence",
                new XElement(xs + "any",
                    new XAttribute("processContents", "skip"),
                    new XAttribute("maxOccurs", "unbounded")
                )
            ),
            new XElement(xs + "attribute",
                new XAttribute("name", "recCount"),
                new XAttribute("default", count) // <--
            ),
            new XElement(xs + "attribute",
                new XAttribute("name", "recLength"),
                new XAttribute("default", length) // <--
            )
        )
    )
);

schema.Save("data.xsd");
```

Please note the writing of the variables `count` and `length` - there should be your data.

The resulting schema will look like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:element name="Table">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:any processContents="skip" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
      </xs:sequence>
      <xs:attribute name="recCount" default="5" />
      <xs:attribute name="recLength" default="42" />
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

Now, when reading an xml document, you must to add this schema - the default attribute values will be taken from it.

```
XElement xml;

var readerSettings = new XmlReaderSettings();
readerSettings.ValidationType = ValidationType.Schema; // <--
readerSettings.Schemas.Add("", "data.xsd"); // <--

using (var reader = XmlReader.Create("data.xml", readerSettings)) // <--
{
    xml = XElement.Load(reader);
}
xml.Save(Console.Out);
Console.WriteLine();
```

The result:

```
<Table recCount="5" recLength="42">
  <Rec recId="1">..</Rec>
  <Rec recId="2">..</Rec>
  <Rec recId="3">..</Rec>
  <Rec recId="4">..</Rec>
  <Rec recId="5">..</Rec>
</Table>
```

Comment: I really appreciate you help. And your approach could be very useful in some scenarios, so I'd remember it. But unfortunately,in my case I just need to create this file and send it to my customers. They do the reading at their side, so there's no way for me to change the way they do it.

Answer (score 0):

You could try to load the xml file into a dataset as it would be easier to compute your attributes that way. Plus the memory management is done by the DataSet layer. Why not give it a try and let us all know too of the results.

Answer (score 0):

I think the [FileStream](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) Class will be helpful to you. Take a look at the Read and Write methods.