# Record program end time at beginning of XML

Tags: c#, xml, datetime

I'm working on a plugin between Autodesk Revit and another platform which needs a XML file exported out of Revit and this XML needs the start and end time recorded at the beginning of it.

Recording the start time is easy but how can I record the end time at the start of my XML? Brief example below.

```
// Some blocks of code here...
string startDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffK");
xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("StartDateTime", startDateTime);
xmlWriter.WriteAttributeString("EndDateTime", endDateTime);  //this obviously causes an error as the variable either not defined, initiated or doesn't have the information yet.
// Some more blocks of code here...
string endDateTime = DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-ddTHH:mm:ss.fffffffK");
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/43186834/5045688 - see answers here

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, thank you, that's exactly what I was after. I'll give it a go.

Comment: Do be aware if you use this kind of technique that your code could easily become dependent on behaviour of the XML serializer that is not guaranteed, for example the order in which attributes are output.

Comment: Good to know, thanks @MichaelKay.